# How to make this jQuery animation code loop forever?

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate, slider, infinite-loop

i am trying to create a loop of text animations over a slider...
i tried loop but it didnt work..
Can you please tell me how do i loop this script forever..thanks

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#header").hide();
    var headerOne='I';
    var headerTwo='Am'; 
    var headerThree='So';
    var headerFour='Cool';
        $("#header").html(headerOne);
    $("#header").fadeIn(1000);
    $('#header').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000,function(){
    $(this).html(headerTwo).fadeIn(1000);
     $('#header').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000,function(){
     $(this).html(headerThree).fadeIn(1000);
     $('#header').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000,function(){
     $(this).html(headerFour).fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);       
      });
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Setinterval could help `setInterval("javascript function",milliseconds);`

Comment: @Bondye if that was an answer it would deserve two downvotes - one for mixing `setInterval` with jQuery animations, and another for passing a string to `setInterval`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you clean your code a bit. You can realize that `setInterval` is not needed. Simply make use of the last callback to repeat the animation.

```
$(function () {
    var $header = $("#header");
    var header = ['I', 'Am', 'So', 'Cool'];
    var position = -1;

    !function loop() {
        position = (position + 1) % header.length;
        $header
            .html(header[position])
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .delay(1000)
            .fadeOut(1000, loop);
    }();
});
```

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/M9S8P/)

Comment: except there's no need for the `.queue` function because the `.html` call is always the first function in the chain.

Comment: Yeah, because of the reordering

Comment: you should perhaps explain the IIFE, though.

Comment: Bravo. I like how you declare a named function and then execute it with the "!()" with recursion. That is the most efficient way of doing this I've seen yet and adding that to my mental toolkit.

Comment: @zipstory.com, yeah, they don't necessarily need to be anonymous though ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use recurence, the last `fadeOut` will execute repeat function when finish.

```
function repeat() {
    $("#header").hide();
    var headerOne='I';
    var headerTwo='Am'; 
    var headerThree='So';
    var headerFour='Cool';
    $("#header").html(headerOne);
    $("#header").fadeIn(1000);
    $('#header').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000,function() {
        $(this).html(headerTwo).fadeIn(1000);
        $('#header').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000,function() {
            $(this).html(headerThree).fadeIn(1000);
            $('#header').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000,function() {
                $(this).html(headerFour).fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).
                    fadeOut(1000, repeat); 
            });
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    repeat();
});
```

Comment: or `$(document).ready(repeat)`, if that's the only function being called

Comment: ah yes, I forgot about that even shorter syntax! ;)

Answer (score -1):

Create a recursive and self-executing function and use it as the final callback:

p.s. Took the liberty to clean up your code.

```
$(function () {
    (function repeat() {
        var header = $("#header"),
            headerOne = 'I',
            headerTwo = 'Am',
            headerThree = 'So',
            headerFour = 'Cool';

        header.text(headerOne)
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .delay(1000)
            .fadeOut(1000, function () {
            header.text(headerTwo)
                .fadeIn(1000)
                .delay(1000)
                .fadeOut(1000, function () {
                header.text(headerThree)
                    .fadeIn(1000)
                    .delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                    header.text(headerFour)
                        .fadeIn(1000)
                        .delay(1000)
                        .fadeOut(1000, repeat);
                });
            });
        });
    })();
});
```

Comment: Alexander did a far better job of cleaning up the code...  Apart from some minor syntax differences this code is otherwise the same as jcubic's.

Comment: @RyanComputerProgrammer IMHO you've accepted the wrong answer.