# Looping text - With fade

Tags: loops, text, fade

i want to make a text, that changes in a loop, with a fade between the changes. I dont no javascript so im not able to make it on my own, i tried to google it with no luck. maybe im just search for the wrong thing but nothing pops up.

Heres a page where they use it right under the banner picture:http://www.spabad.dk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No using javascript means you want to do this in pure CSS. It could be difficult to get the exact result that you want, although you can find effects close to what you need : [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/dt5uuty1/).

If you are ok with using javascript, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/M9S8P/) is what you're looking for (note that jquery was included, this is a javascript library that simplifies its use. You can easily include it in an html page by putting `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>` in your `<head>`

Hope that helps!

Sources: [Simple CSS Animation Loop – Fading In & Out "Loading" Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985018/simple-css-animation-loop-fading-in-out-loading-text) and 
[How to make this jQuery animation code loop forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474566/how-to-make-this-jquery-animation-code-loop-forever)

Comment: Thanks a lot man ;) i feel like such a rookie :P 

But what can you expect :P having only a couple of months experience with web ;)

Comment: But can i make it loop different text in the css only ? :) and the javascript you linked, is broken theres a error ;)

Comment: I edited the link ;)
I think it's truly in your interest to use javascript if you plan on progressing in web development! You won't go very far with only CSS.

Comment: Well im a Graphics student in Denmark, started at the school 2 months ago ;) they are going to teach us the basics of web like html and css. Its mostly because i have personal interest in web development ;)

Comment: Anyways thanks a lot!, im going to use the Javascript, it seem to be a very simple script ;)